# PHP file_exists if/then statement

Tags: php

This is my first time playing with PHP, and I'm having trouble making a basic if/then statement. I want to do something like

if file exists
 show the html code 
else
 show different html code.

Here's where I'm at currently --

```
<?php
if ( file_exists('pdf/'.'htmlspecialchars($_POST['apt'], ENT_COMPAT)'.'.pdf') {
    echo "the file exists";
}  else {
    echo "file does not exist";
}
?>
```

I think the problem here is how I wrote the

```
file_exists('pdf/'.'htmlspecialchars($_POST['apt'], ENT_COMPAT)'.'.pdf')
```

Thoughts greatly appreciated!

Comment: why do you put a function call into `'` ? And also you are missing a closing `)` from the `if ()` statement.

Comment: Hi GBD, I don't think I have a proper set up, becuase any time I make an error in PHP, I just get a 500 internal server error.

Comment: just remove htmlspecialchars. If someone tries to send a char like & the if will fail anyways since characters like &, <, and " aren't allowed in file names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems. Firstly, you are missing a closing bracket at the end of your `if` condition, and secondly you have quotes where you should not, surrounding the call to `htmlspecialchars`.

The correct code would be:

```
if (file_exists('pdf/'.htmlspecialchars($_POST['apt'], ENT_COMPAT).'.pdf')) {
    echo "the file exists";
}  else {
    echo "file does not exist";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
if (file_exists('pdf/' . htmlspecialchars($_POST['apt'], ENT_COMPAT) . '.pdf')) {
    echo "the file exists";
} else {
    echo "file does not exist";
}
```

You had some quotes before calling `htmlspecialchars()`. When you call a function you don't need quotes.
See also that you didn't close a bracket.

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem of quotes:

```
file_exists('pdf/'.htmlspecialchars($_POST['apt'], ENT_COMPAT).'.pdf')
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont need htmlspecialchars. It will convert improper chars into even more improper chars. For example ' becomes & # 0 3 9 ; (without spaces)

Comment: This is not the answer! If you have friendly advice then comment on the question, or answer the question and add your advice at the end

Comment: This is most definitly *an* answer. Just ask him to request a file named "&^%$#.pdf and you'll see that htmlspecialchars is not only pointless but will compound the problem.

Comment: Does it solve the issue that he is having? No it doesn't, it advises him that the function is not necessary. The correct answer is the one that has been accepted. +1 for the good advice, but this is not an answer :-)

Comment: I 100% agree with you that the `htmlspecialchars` function will cause problems for files with special characters, along with it not being necessary anyway, but this was not what was causing the problem in his case :-)

Comment: I saw the htmlspecialchars call and ignored the rest. The script error was from incorect syntax, MitchS got it right